# почему минимакс ходит в центральную клетку ноликом в игре крестики нолики

Tags: delphi-7

вот полный урок крестиков ноликов и алгоритм минимакс: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2751&v=2Dw_QNTK3P8 но не понятно, почему минимакс выбирает центральную клетку когда ходит ноликом

Comment: приведите код в вопросе, никто не будет тратить время на какие-то непонятные ютуб-уроки

Answer (score 0):

вот код Делфи, но не понятно, почему минимакс выбирает центральную клетку когда ходит ноликом.

```
procedure TForm1.MiniMax(var Value: ShortInt; Game1, Game2: ShortInt); // минимакс
var
  i: Byte;
  Score, Temp: ShortInt;
begin

WinFound(Value); // поиск победных комбинаций

if Value <> 0 then Exit;

Score := -2;

for i := 1 to 9 do

if Board[i] = 0 then

begin

Board[i] := Game1;

MiniMax(Temp, Game2, Game1);

Board[i] := 0;

case Temp of
 -1: Temp :=  1;
  1: Temp := -1;
  0: Temp :=  0;
end;

if Temp > Score then Score := Temp;

end;

case Score of
 -1: Value := -1;
  1: Value :=  1;
  0: Value :=  0;  //итоговое значение от всего перебора. 0 - значит ничья.
end;

end;
```